# switch between video qualities in html5 video

Tags: html, video

I was able to switch between different video extensions depending on whether or not it's supported, however, how can i **switch between different videos** that are the same extension but **different sizes** and thus different quality.

Here's my code:

```
<video style="z-index: 1;position:absolute; left: 50%;top: 50%; margin: 10% 0 0    -250px;"
controls
preload="auto" width="510" height="300" poster="" 
data-setup="{}">
<source src="vid/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="vid/video.webm" type='video/webm'>
<p> Your current browser does not support the video format. Please consider upgrading    your browser or using a different one</p>
</video>
```

Comment: you will need to ask the user to select (eg HD or SD) and change the source. If you use the canPlayType function you can determine what you need to present to the user to reduce the number of sources you need to juggle at any one time. Hard to do this automatically reliably in javascript but using MediaSource to manually stream chunks would get you there

Comment: Defeats the purpose, I want it to automatically switch between qualities without asking the user.

Comment: HLS gives you that, but isn't available across most desktop browsers today (not part of the HTML5 video spec), hence my suggestion of using MediaSource to build your own (or re-purpose something like the sample MPEG-DASH implementations). Maybe one day DASH will be as common as mp4 or webm but not today